Long occlusive combined with syllable break
The transcription of the word ecce in ecclesiastical pronunciation doesn't make sense to me, as there is a combination of a syllable break and a long occlusive.
These are the two notations for /ecce/: ['et.t͡ʃe] - ['et͡ːʃe].
The two c make the [t] sound, and at the same time in the middle of the two c there's a syllable break. I was thinking something close to the percussive bilabial [ʬ], like a percussive t and an unpercussive t, something like:
Percussive diacritic ꜛ, Unpercussive diacritic ꜜ   --->   ['etꜛ.tꜜ͡ʃe]
In this way, the long [t] is emulated and we still manage to see the syllable break. Is there any other formal/official way to write this, or should we add a new diacritic in the IPA?
Note
I don't think [t.t] is equivalent to [t:], as with [t.t] you have to unarticulate [t] and then rearticulate it, for example [t.t.t.t.t] is like emulating gun shots and not a really a long [t::::]. Am I crazy?

The reason we tend to use /t.t/ as phonetically equivalent to /tː/ is that usually they are equivalent. It is almost universally the case that when two identical occlusive phonemes directly follow each other, there will be only one physical occlusion and one release for the group, unless they’re deliberately pronounced very distinctly and separately (e.g., ‘but to go’ is normally [bət̚.tʰə ˈɡəʊ], while ‘but: to go’ might be [ˈbətʰ | tʰə ˈɡəʊ]).

I remember arguing with someone about this for Italian. In English, there is one sound but in Italian two sounds for a word like frittata. That's what makes Italian so charming.

If you want a narrow phonetic trascription, it can be written as ['et̚.t͡ʃe]. The arrows are not actually percussive or "unpercussive" diacritics but are used for signifying tone.
[t.t] is just a broad transcription here, just like in some English dialects "cat" can be pronounced [kæt̚] but still gets transcribed as [kæt].

Indeed in most forms of English, cat will more likely be [kʰæʔt̚] (with some variation in how far front/back or low the vowel is).

I know the arrows are not for percussiveness, it was a way to represent the idea. How is this diacritic named? t̚

@Agente156 No audible release.

Syllable breaks are not a phonetic entity, which is why on Wiktionary, the transcription "ˈet.t͡ʃe" actually appears between phonemic slashes, not phonetic brackets: "/ˈet.t͡ʃe/, [ˈɛtː͡ʃe]".
The reason for supposing there is a syllable break is because Latin phonotactics doesn't allow a long consonant sound to occur at the start or end of a syllable: e.g. you can't have a syllable like cce or ecc in Latin. (The words "hic" and "hoc" seem to have been pronounced in Classical Latin with a long [kː] sound when followed by a word starting with a vowel, but this was probably simplified to short [k] before a consonant.) In other words, the syllable break is theoretical, not something you should be trying to pronounce.
In terms of pronunciation, what you have is as follows:

An approach phase, where the tongue is put in place behind the alveolar ridge to articulate a postalveolar stop
A hold phase, where the tongue is pressed firmly enough against the top of the mouth to block airflow. Since [tː͡ʃ] is a long consonant, the hold phase is maintained for a longer period of time than it is for the short counterpart [tʃ]
A release phase. After the extended hold period, the stop portion of the affricate is released, meaning the tongue lets some air past it. Since [tː͡ʃ] is an affricate sound, the release involves audible frication: even though air is moving past the tongue, the tongue is positioned in such a way that it partially obstructs the airflow and produces a [ʃ] sound.

That's it. There's nothing in the middle of the hold phase that separates the "t" and "t͡ʃ" in "/ˈet.t͡ʃe/": despite the presence of a syllable break in the phonemic notation, it is not a stop followed by a distinct affricate /t͡ʃ/, but merely an extended affricate.
